# Tell if BufferedInputStream is closed

Tags: java, android

I have two threads (the main thread and a worker thread).

The worker thread reads input from some socket source (via BufferedInputStream to make it possible to "go back"), packs read data into a data structure and adds the result to a BlockingQueue (which is thread-safe).

At some moment the main thread decides to finish with it and closes the BufferedInputStream.

***How can the worker thread find out if the BufferedInputStream is closed?***

Normally, mInputStream.read() returns -1 on EOF, but this does not happen when the stream is closed. Instead, an IOException is thrown telling me that the stream is closed.

The worker thread has to wind-up gracefully, but how does ***it*** find out that the stream is closed?

It cannot tell the reason from the exception class: the class is just IOException.
It could test if `e.getMessage().contains("closed")`, but it is error-prone: on some version of Android the message may happen to be "CLOSED" or "not open", while prose like "unless closed" will result in a false positive.

The best thing that comes to my mind is:

```
private static boolean _isOpen(InputStream inputStream) {
    try {
        inputStream.available();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This side effect (throwing an exception) is sort of documented, BUT testing if the stream is closed is not the primary functionality of *available()*; one day somebody will write an implementation that just returns 0.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can't you just read from the input stream until it fails (catching IOException) and then exit gracefully from the method? Having an `isOpen` is vulnerable for a race-condition, so that's no good either.

Comment: You could also tell your worker thread that it should stop working with the stream once it is closed, i.e. have a `worker.setWorking(false)` or something and a `if (isWorking) { read(); }` in your worker.

Comment: @Patrick probably yes, but the worker thread will be inside `read()` when the stream is closed; I could check like `catch(IOException e) { if (isWorking) {...}}`

Answer (score -1):

Exceptions are meant to be used for "exceptional" state conditions only, such as connection fail or disk fail.

So it sounds as if you can't have the main thread instruct the worker-thread to stop dealing with the stream, which is what would normally happen in a scenario where the main thread owns the resources.

Also, the JDK documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.htmls states:

> The *available* method for class *InputStream* always returns 0.
>
> Throws:
>       IOException - if an I/O error occurs.

And as is suggested in the comments of the question: simply read from the stream and catch IOExceptions. If the resource becomes unavailable, the worker thread will notice by getting exceptions that way.

Comment: Folks, please do not downvote the answers! For example, this answer was useful to me because it provided additional info on the question.

Comment: Oh I don' mind too much. Just guessing but I think the down-voter found the question in itself not of quality enough, and hence down-voted the answer to it. See also the SO meta discussions. In this case though, you could have rephrased the question, because the difficulty is that exceptions do not cross into other threads, and that IS a more interesting problem. At least, in my opinion.